# Where can I find what Magento files I am using in my repository?

Tags: xml, git, magento

I have become the recipient of a Magento code base that is the result of many developers before me who have not had much experience with Magento. Admittedly, I'm new to it myself, but do have an understanding of MVC frameworks and OOP.

In many cases, the files would be duplicated and modified with new code.  For example:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/newtheme/template/catalog/product/view

list.phtml
list_2013_08_06a.phtml
list_2013_09_12a.phtml
...and so on...
```

This would be fine, if the xml files were still pointing to `list.phtml` and the other files were simply used as backup, but if I look into...

```
/app/design/frontend/default/newtheme/layout
```

... I find that the xml has code will *sometimes* point to `list.phtml` and *sometimes* point to `list_2013_08_06a.phtml` ... ALSO, sometimes an xml file in the layout could be `catalog.xml` or it could be `catalog_09_10_13.xml` because the previous developers knew nothing of source control. (I have since created a git repository for our company.)

So, my question is, how does one determine what files are actually in use with Magento in those folders? I'm trying to prune as I go along, but this code is so extremely bloated that I was hoping for some way of trimming all of the unneeded files.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turn on Magento's template path hints. [Magneto Debug](https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug) is awesome, too.

Comment: I'd never heard of Magneto Debug. It looks like it's been dormant for some time. What version will it work with?

Answer (score 1):

Only way is to find pages in XML layout files. I was in simmilar situaton and helps for me to add to each page

```
<!-- file: <?php echo __FILE__; ?> -->
```

And in each template i can locate real file position.

Comment: That's a great idea!  I'm going to give that a try and see if I can start pruning from there!